# Is a field also a vector subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this doubt, I can consider a field also a subspace? For example I have the vector space of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{K}$ in the indeterminate $x$:  $\mathbb{K}_{<=n}$ . If $n=0$ I have $\mathbb{K}$ which is a field, so it is a vector subspace and in general every field is a subspace?

Comment: For $n$ I mean the degree of the polynomial

Comment: Is every field a subspace of what? Certainly $K$ is a subspace of $K[x]$.

Comment: Any $K$-algebra is, in particular, a vector space over $K$.

Comment: I guess, more generally, a "subspace" of a space is any subset which is a vector space. In particular, $K$ is a subspace of any vector space containing $K$; there is nothing to prove here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if $\Bbb L$ is a field and $\Bbb K$ is a subfield of $\Bbb L$, then $\Bbb L$ is a vector space over $\Bbb K$. This follows simply from the axioms of fields and vector spaces.

Examples:
${\Bbb Q}(\sqrt 2) = \{a+b\sqrt 2\mid a,b\in{\Bbb Q}\}$ is a 2-dim. vector space over $\Bbb Q$. ${\Bbb R}$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$. ${\Bbb C} = \{a+ib\mid a,b\in{\Bbb R}\}$ is a 2-dim. vector space over $\Bbb R$. ${\Bbb F}_{q^n}$ with $q$ a prime power is an $n$-dim. vector space over ${\Bbb F}_q$.

Comment: But could exist a $1-dim$ vector space?

Comment: As a special case, $\Bbb K$ is a vector space over $\Bbb K$ with basis $\{1\}$.